# Competition Chances - Probability

Tags: probability

the chances of winning a competition is 1 in 14000. if I buy 14000 tickets what are my chances of winning?

My answer would be $ 1-({\frac{13999}{14000}})^{14000}$

Is this correct? and i am supposed to approximate this expression, how would i do so (using taylor series expansion of log(1+H))

Comment: That depends on lots of things that you have not specified in your question.  For example, if there are $14000$ tickets and you buy them all, obviously your chance of winning is $1$.

Comment: The tickets are like lotto tickets in the question so the amount of tickets in circulation is irrelevant

Comment: Provided all the dangling details (independence of chances for each ticket, for a start) are answered, the answer would be more like $1-(1-\frac{1}{14000})^{14000}$. The probability to win is the complement of the probability that all $14000$ tickets lose. Now, you can approximate this by remembering, for starters, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$.

Comment: Changing your question that asked for correctness of what you had done, after receiving a comment/answer pointing out where something was wrong, doesn't really make sense. That's not how questions and answers are supposed to work.

Comment: I understand that, but the correction in question was merely a typo which I had made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P=1-({\frac{13999}{14000}})^{14000}$$

let $a=14000$ then

$$x\equiv ({\frac{13999}{14000}})^{14000}=(1-1/a)^a$$

taking logs and using $\ln (1-x )\sim -x$

$$ln(x) = a \ln(1-1/a) \sim a(-1/a)=-1$$

so $P=1-e^{-1}\sim  63.2\%$ is good to about 5 decimal places.